# How do I buffer an image, show it when I want to, and be able to move it

Tags: javascript, image, animation

I looked forever for how to do this but can't figure out how. The best I have done is made an image with HTML. I tried to edit the image settings after it was made like how you use `document.getElementById()` to change text, but I couldn't get it to work.

my code so far...

```
    function run() {
    x++;
    y++;
    if (x==10 || x==30) {
        exmp.visibility = show //doesn't work
    }
    if (x==20 || x==40) {
        exmp.visibility = hidden //doesn't work
    }
    if (x==50) {
        x=0
        y=0
    }
    document.getElementById("exmp").style = "position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; WIDTH:239px; HEIGHT:74px" //doesn't work
}
x=0
y=0
document.write("<div ID=\"exmp\"; STYLE=\"position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; WIDTH:239px; HEIGHT:74px\">  <IMG SRC=\"exmp.png\"; alt=\"image\"> </div>");
setInterval(run,33);
```

Comment: Please show excerpts from what you've tried so far.

Comment: What "settings" are you trying to modify? What are you wanting to do with the image? Make it fly around the page? Resize it? Pull a rabbit out of it? We need more detail to be able to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a great java script tutorial on moving images and making them display when I want to. (http://www.openjs.com/tutorials/advanced_tutorial/moving.php)

my working code:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Image Mover</title>
<style>
DIV.movable { position:absolute; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div ID="exmp"; class = "movable";>
<IMG SRC="exmp.png"; alt="image"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("exmp").style.visibility='hidden';

function run() {
    pos++;
    if (pos==10 || pos==30) {
        document.getElementById("exmp").style.visibility='visible';
    }
    if (pos==20 || pos==40) {
        document.getElementById("exmp").style.visibility='hidden';
    }
    if (pos==40) {
        pos=0;
    }
    //document.getElementById("exmp").style = "position:absolute; TOP:"
     //      +pos+"px; LEFT:"+pos+"px; WIDTH:239px; HEIGHT:74px";
    document.getElementById("exmp").style.left = pos+"px";
    document.getElementById("exmp").style.top = pos+"px";
    //STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:0px; LEFT:0px; WIDTH:239px; HEIGHT:74px"
}
pos=0;
setInterval(run,33);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Several ways to do this.

1. You can cache the image using JavaScript without displaying it:

   var img = new Image();
   img.src = "http://**PATH_TO_IMAGE**";

When needed, you can append this image element to the page.

1. You can add a img tag to the page, but set the image to invisible (visibility: hidden), or make it very small, like 1px x 1px. The browser will load the image, draw the image slot, but it is transparent. To use this method, you need to make sure you put this image somewhere user wont notice it.

Comment: how do I set the image to be visible?

Comment: change the style of the element, for example: img {visibility:hidden;}